# April fools 2023?

Tags: discussion, fun

I visited AD on April 1st this year (as well as every day in March and April) but I didn't see anything for April fools. I have seen other posts on AD Meta on April fools for other years but I'm not sure if they did something in 2023.

Did they? What was it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no April fools this year. They planned something, see this bug report on Meta Stack Exchange: ["//Todo: Remove after April Fools 2023 is done"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387507/295232) but I've read somewhere that they cancelled it; I don't remember the exact reason.

Comment: Oh alright, tell me if you find the reason why they cancelled it. Thanks.